# Unable to send messages bigger than 8k in size in Paho - Javascript

Tags: javascript, activemq-classic, mqtt, paho

I've been trying to send large messages over mqtt with paho for javascript.
But if the message is bigger than 8 kb the websocket closes and i'm unable to send the message.

I've been using the following function after connect to send a message.

```
function onConnect() {
   console.log("onConnect");
   var bigString ="";
  client.subscribe("topic");

  for (var i = 0;i <8200;i++){
     bigString+="a"
  }
  message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(bigString);
  message.destinationName = "topic";
  client.send(message);
}
```

The result is always:

```
onConnectionLost:AMQJS0008I Socket closed.
```

If the length is below 8000 bytes everything works fine. 
I'm using an ActiveMQ server.

Is this a Paho limitation?
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried with another broker (e.g. mosquitto) to see if it is the paho client or activemq?

Comment: I've tried doing a java client using paho for java, and had no problems.
But i'll try with mosquitto.

Comment: The java client would not be accessing the broker via websockets so not following the same path

Comment: Would be sensible to check your broker configuration to see if a limit is configured on the WS layer.

Comment: @TimBish I checked that. The transport layer for websockets is the same size as all the other transports, and they're huge.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the maximum packet size defined by the server to which you have connected to is 8kb. If you try to send a message greater than 8kb the connection will be closed by the server. Hence you need to ensure that the messages you send do not exceed the maximum packet size defined by the server. The maximum packet size is defined in the CONNACK packet sent by the server in response to the client's CONNECT packet. Refer https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/best-practices-of-maximum-packet-size-in-mqtt.
However I think this mechanism of negotiating the packet size is a feature of MQTT v5 and this may not be helpful for you.